# Distance in Mumbai City?

Tags: hotels, mumbai

Does anyone know how far is US Consulate General from Trident hotel, Mumbai? Both are in Bandra Kurla Complex but I was wondering if the consulate is at walking distance or little bit far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because typing queries into Google maps on others' behalf is not a productive use of our time.

Comment: Just forget about the consulate and walk over to Indigo, relax, and drink  :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be looked up directly on Google Maps

Answer (score 1):

The hotel distance is barely 150 meters. Refer [Google Map](https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/Trident+Hotel,+plot+34+Santacruz+Electronic+Export+Processing+Zone,+Andheri+East,+Mumbai,+Maharashtra/US+Consulate+General+(+Embassy+),+C-49,+G-Block,+Bandra+Kurla+Complex,+Bandra+East,+Mumbai,+Maharashtra+400051/@19.0658967,72.8657013,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x3be7c81f6aaaaaab:0xc6a35201d242fcb7!2m2!1d72.867814!2d19.066569!1m5!1m1!1s0x3be7cdd8ba12301b:0x821788f8f3f7e720!2m2!1d72.8681788!2d19.0652785).